# Generate Row Count, increasing in 10,000 per row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm needing to return a generated ID where for each row it increases by 10,000.

For example, the ExpectedResult column in the below, and if there are more rows, it would increase by 10,000 each time.

```
Create Table #temp
(
    ID uniqueidentifier,
    ExpectedResult int
)
insert into #temp
(
    ID,
    ExpectedResult
)
select
    NEWID(),
    10000
union
select
    NEWID(),
    20000
union
select
    NEWID(),
    30000
union
select
    NEWID(),
    40000
union
select
    NEWID(),
    50000

select * from #temp
order by ExpectedResult

drop table #temp
```

I've found the example below, but I'm not sure how to increase the count by 10,000 each time

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100))
```

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a sequence 10000, 20000, etc., of arbitrary length?

Comment: Why not just use an id that increments by 1 (easy to generate!) and create a view that multiplies it by 10000?

Comment: Good plan @Nick, have done that.

Comment: @Philip, you have to be careful if you are planning to use incremental field. you should avoid gaps and also consider concurrency when generating new id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Nick in the original question comments, have done this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100))*10000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later (including SQL Server 2017), you could create a numbering sequence using `CREATE SEQUENCE`. 
To create SEQUENCE with increment of 10000, add the clause `INCREMENT BY`.

For example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1  
    START WITH 10000  
    INCREMENT BY 10000
```

For more information, please consult this SQL Server documentation on `CREATE SEQUENCE`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cte` to generate `N number` for `guids`. Below is a sample cte to generate 100 rows for your `guid`.

```
Drop table #temp
Create Table #temp
(
    ID uniqueidentifier,
    ExpectedResult int
);

with cte as(
     select  newid() as new_id, 10000 as ctr
     union all 
     select new_id, ctr + 10000 from cte where ctr/10000 < 100
)
insert into #temp
select * from cte  option (MaxRecursion 0 );


select * from #temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide ROW_NUMBER() by 10000 and then multiply by 10000
You can write something like this

```
select *, rowNum10K = 10000 * (1 + (row_number() over (order by object_id)) / 10000)
from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the column as an `identity` to do this for you:

```
Create Table temp (
    ID uniqueidentifier,
    ExpectedResult int identity (10000, 10000)
);

insert into temp (ID)
    select v.id
    from (values (NEWID()), (NEWID()), (NEWID()), (NEWID()), (NEWID())) v(id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c8198a8f533597f8dfa0820405eaad2) is a db<>fiddle.